# Create OpenExcel and download it

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this code for creating an Excel file and then sending it for download:

```
Stream stream = Stream.Null;
using (ExcelDocument doc = ExcelDocument.CreateWorkbook(stream)) 
{
     ExcelWorksheet wsheet = doc.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Assessment");
     doc.EnsureStylesDefined();
     // add some cells              
}

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=Assessment.xlsx;charset=utf-8;");
Response.BinaryWrite(Utilities.Utilities.ConvertFileToByteArray(stream));
Response.End();
```

When it gets to end of the **using**, I get this error :

> File contains corrupted data.

If I save file to my disk it works fine.

where I went wrong?

I'm using this [Component](http://openexcel.codeplex.com/).

Comment: can you please say when the exception raises.

Comment: @Nag : right before **Response.ContentType**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change first line to :

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
```

Also Change

```
Response.BinaryWrite(Utilities.Utilities.ConvertFileToByteArray(stream));
```

to

```
Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
```